# App icon not changing after updating App

Tags: iphone, icons, app-store

Getting reports that, after updating our app, the springboard icon does not update, requiring the device to be turned off and on for the change to take effect.

This has happened when updating from a live version to a test build (via iTunes) and updating from an old (live) version to the latest live version (via appstore on device).

This isn't a regular occurrence, but I am wondering what might be causing this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use "Build > Clean all Targets" and then build and run. Xcode doesn't always see that images have been updated, and leaves them out of incremental builds. Cleaning before building makes Xcode build the app file from scratch, and will pick up any images it's failing to get.

Comment: I don't think it's an Xcode issue. When the icon doesn't update on one device, it does on another device even though it is the same build. The issue doesn't seem to be device or iOS related, nor are there any steps the will reproduce the issue on a regular basis.

Comment: Brilliant! This did it for me.

Comment: nope, it does not. icon files get reused and new ones never show up till I delete the app completely and reinstall new version of it. at least that is how it goes with my builds.

Comment: Great, this did it for me, too!

Comment: @user1120133 you have another person thanking you. Could you potentially explain _why_ Xcode doesn't always update? No worries if not - thanks!

Comment: In my case I held the `Option key` on the `Product` menu and selected `Clean Build Folder` (Xcode 7.3.1)

Answer (score 4):

I was facing this issue and none of the provided answers here or somewhere else helped me so I did next steps.

**For X-Code 8+**

I've **opened my project viewer**

[image: Assets in project viewer]

Then I've chosen Assets

Right-clicked there and I've chosen **App Icons & Launch Images -> New iOS App icon**

[image: Create new iOS App Icon]

Attach the images, that you want to resolutions of your app icon in your newly created AppIcon asset (rename it as you want)

Then **go to the project settings and choose new app icon there**

[image]

It worked for me

Answer (score 4):

If I uninstall the app, restart the phone and then install the app again, it works correctly. I think some issue with the app cache.