# how to change xcode app icon?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have been trying to change my apps icon, but i cannot seem to do it.  I have been following this example: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/chapters/AddingLaunchImagestoanAssetCatalog.html

but no matter what i do,  i cannot get the icon to change.  whenever i add an image, it just gives me an error saying that it is the incorrect size,  but when i change the size of the image xcode tells me a new size.

is there something that isn't in this example that i would be missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [App icon not changing after updating App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809700/app-icon-not-changing-after-updating-app)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This is](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/chapters/AddingLaunchImagestoanAssetCatalog.html) a good way, you should do something like this:

[image]

For example:

- 40pt - 120:120 for @3x, 80:80 for @2x , 40:40 for @1x
- for artworks 512:512 for @1x and 1024:1024 for @2x

Be attentive with icon sizes, and everything will be ok :)

Answer (score 1):

I personally like to use this [site](http://makeappicon.com) to make my app icons. Just upload a fairly large icon artwork and they will send you an email with all the configured sizes.

In the file, go into the `iOS` folder and look for a folder called `AppIcon.appiconset`. Copy that.

Go into your app's source folder and into your `images.xcassets` folder. Now paste in that copied folder and say replace.

Answer (score 0):

Resize them manually and then add them there by drag and drop

example: Size = 1x * 29pt = 29x29

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the section on images and icons in the [Apples humane interface guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html), it goes over the different sizes that you need. And don't forget to append the @2x and @3x to the name of your icons!

Answer (score 0):

First you need to convert the image then drag it into assets -> AppIcon

visit this website for converting icon 
https://makeappicon.com

After converting the icon on the website they will mail you all the converted icons on your mail id, then you need to select the image icon form the provided list according to the size.[image]